# $\{1,\dots,n\}$ - Without further definitions, does that imply $n \geq 1$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have another extremely basic notation question:

In many books, wikipedia and other places they write $\{1,\dots,n\}$ without ever defining n.

Does that imply that $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ or does that also allow $ n \in \mathbb{Z} $, which would mean that the set could also be empty?

(Sorry if this has already been answered somewhere, I find it very hard to find the right search terms for these kind of questions)

Comment: If they don't define $n$, then most times, that means that what $n$ is is clear from the context. Most times, $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: Not clear... With "include" do you mean "a member of..." ($\in$)? In set theory [Inclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) is "to be a subset of..." ($\subseteq$).

Comment: This because the empty set is a subset (included into) every set.

Comment: sorry, I reworded the question now to make that more clear.

Comment: You seem to be asking whether, when $n=0$, does $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}=\emptyset$.  This is indeed the natural interpretation. Whether $n$ can be $0$ depends on other information not in the question

Comment: @Mauro I think the meaning "does the collection of sets expressible in the form $\{1,\dots,n\}$ include the empty set?"

Comment: “$1,\dots,n$” implies $n\in\Bbb N$ in the same way $\sum_{k=1}^n$ implies $n$ is an integer greater than (maybe equal to) $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context and the intentions of the author. In many
instances we define $\,[n] := \{1,2,\dots,n\}\,$ and intend it to be
used when $\,n>0.\,$ However, in other instances, we allow $\,n=0\,$
in which case $\,[0] = \emptyset := \{\} \,$ is the set with zero elements. It
all depends on the situation and the author. Sometimes $\,n=0\,$ does
makes sense, but at other times it does not. You can think of
this as merely a matter of convention exactly similar to the
convention that an empty summation is equal to zero.

Note that $\,[m]\subseteq [n]\,$ iff $\,m\le n\,$ which includes
the special case $\,\emptyset = [0]\subseteq [n]\,$ for all
$\,n\ge 0.\,$

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when we have a set of the form

$$\{1, \dots, n\}$$

we are referring to the set of natural numbers from $1$ to $n,$ where $n$ is some natural number ($n \in \mathbb{N}$).

Also, note that $\emptyset$ is not “included” in the above set, for some object $x$ be included in a set $X$ it has to be the case that $x \in X,$ i.e., $x$ is an element of $X.$

In this case, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it is clear that $\emptyset \notin \{1,\dots, n\}.$

Although, the empty set is a subset of $\{1,\dots,n\},$ i.e., $\emptyset \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$ (it is the case that $\emptyset$ is a subset of any set).

Comment: Thank you, very much for this answer.

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: And yes, the question was poorly worded - I didn't think about the fact, that "include" is actually also the mathematical term in English.

Comment: Always use the mathematical definition of a term beside the colloquial meaning, that is the idea behind :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you consider the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ where $n\geq 0$ is an integer, then the case $n=0$ is defined as the empty set.